# SML: find maximal element in a given column of a list

Tags: list, find, sml, max

I need to find a greatest element in the given COLUMN of the list:

```
myList = [(1,2,0), (3,5,8), (9,1,2)]
```

Something like this:

```
max(myList(:,2)) // maximal element in the 2nd column
```

In this example the answer should be 5.

I wrote the following code, but how can I put the 1st or 2nd column into the input of "max"?

```
fun findSum(myList:MyList) = max(#1 myList) + max(#2 myList)

fun max [] = 0
  | max (x::xs) = foldl Int.max x xs
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to map the appropriate selector onto the list, then using max on the result of that.

```
max (map #2 myList)
```

Note, of course, there's no way to do it for tuples of arbitrary size (due to types), and no easy way to convert an integer into a selector. (Apart from creating a function where you manually map each integer onto the appropriate selector.)